# How to save table view cell data user inputs on a daily basis?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a food diary in my app, I want the user to be able to save all the food they eat, and then be able to refer to it in the future. Heres a pic of my app: [image: app gui]

So basically I want to know how can i save the values of the food the user inputs in my table view cells, then let the user be able to press the back button/forward button on my navigation bar to retrieve the food he's eaten the past couple days. Do i need to use a server? Will saving the food on a daily basis take up too much data on the iphone? Can someone point me in the right direction, I'm not sure where to start on this.

Comment: you can do using sqlite database . FMDB is the best library for sqlite.

Comment: there are lots of options https://rollout.io/blog/ios-databases-sqllite-core-data-realm/ in some ways, the best one is the one where you can get the tutorials working most easily!  The volume of data you're talking about should be tiny compared to storing photos, so I wouldn't worry too much about that

Comment: @russell cool thank you! Is there any process to make the values of the tableview cell save?

Comment: yes :-)  Most of the local databases will have to-do list tutorials available.  That will be almost exactly the same as you need for this.